# MatchQ returns False for a match for e1 ** e2 while matching both e1 and e2

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I used a simple predicate `realQ[x_] := MemberQ[{Real, Integer, Rational}, Head[x]]`. With that predicate
both `MatchQ[2 e1, (k1_?realQ  x_)]` and `MatchQ[(- 2 e2), (k2_?realQ  y_)]` returned `True`. But `MatchQ[2 e1 ** (- 2 e2), (k1_?realQ  x_) ** (k2_?realQ  y_)]` returned `False`. Any suggestion as to why that happened?

Comment: Did you already look at the result of `FullForm[2 e1 ** (-2 e2)]` and compare it with the result of `FullForm[(2 e1) ** (-2 e2)]`?

Comment: You were missing a `_` for the `x_` parameter in the definition of `realQ`; I assume that you actually had that in your notebook, or all your `MatchQ` expressions would return `False` without it.

Answer (score 3):

Your seem to want your last expression interpreted as `(2 e1) ** (-2 e2)`, i.e the NonCommutativeMultiply between `(2 e1)` and `(2 e2)`.

However, regular multiplication (`Times`) has lower priority than `NonCommutativeMultiply`, so the expression as you wrote it actually interpreted as though it was grouped this way:

```
2 e1 ** (-2 e2) == 2 ( e1 ** (-2 e2) )
```

You can see that using [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html):

```
FullForm[2 e1 ** (-2 e2)]

(* Out: Times[2, NonCommutativeMultiply[e1, Times[-2, e2]]] *)
```

To enforce your interpretation, you need to add an explicit set of parentheses:

```
(2 e1) ** (-2 e2)

FullForm[(2 e1) ** (-2 e2)]
(* Out: NonCommutativeMultiply[Times[2, e1], Times[-2, e2]] *)
```

The latter expression will match your pattern:

```
Clear[realQ]
realQ[x_] := MemberQ[{Real, Integer, Rational}, Head[x]]

MatchQ[2 e1, (k1_?realQ x_)]
(* Out: True *)

MatchQ[(-2 e2), (k2_?realQ y_)]
(* Out: True *)

MatchQ[(2 e1) ** (-2 e2), (k1_?realQ x_) ** (k2_?realQ y_)]
(* Out: True *)
```

Comment: A hint that precedence is coming into play can be seen if you triple-click on the `**` in the expression `2 e1 ** (-2 e2)` in the frontend; you'll quickly see that what's being operated on by `**` isn't what was expected.